# rails: default created_at field custom format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, format

I have a table in rails which ive used the default for timestamps.
For example in my applications table I have
`applicant.created_at` to show when the application was submitted.
However this shows the full format of both date and time.

Is there a way for me just to display the date only in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of great tutorials for formatting time.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/31-formatting-time

but what you are looking for is .strftime

```
t = Time.now
t.strftime("Printed on %m/%d/%Y")
puts t #=> "Printed on 11/14/2012"
```

http://strfti.me/

Comment: This is correct for display, note that it won't help you in handling input from forms. For that you need Time.parse or a gem like Chronic.